# cakephp: how to display foreign key table field

Tags: cakephp-2.0

basically,

**database table**:

1. Products: id, name
2. Comments: productId,comment

**Model:**
product.php

```
class Product extends AppModel {
  public $hasMany = array('Comment'=>array('foreignkey'=>'productId'));
}
```

comment.php

```
class Comment extends AppModel {
  public $belongsTo = array('Product');
}
```

In product index.ctp, how can I display one product comment? What I need to write in ProductsController.php and index.ctp?

Comment: displaying one product comment need just a find query to get one (first) in comment controller , really i dont understand your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the CakePHP conventions ([CakePHP Convention over Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)) then all of this will be done automagically for you, it requires foreign keys to be named product_id rather than productId (although you have setup the foreign key in the relationship - it is just easier to start from the beginning following the conventions).

You should also specify the class name in the relationship:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
    )
);
```

In your case what you should do in the controller is:

```
$products = $this->Product->find('all');
```

This will fetch all your products and any associated comments on those Products (and also any other associated models you have declared in the Product Model)

If you want to read more about setting this up you can check out [CakePHP - Retrieving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)